# show item number total only in the minicart

Tags: php, opencart

I want to show item number total only in the minicart that is in the header.(OpenCart v1.5.6.4)

**I get this currently** (according to OpenCart functionality)

```
==For O item==
Shopping Cart 0 item(s) - $0.00

==For 1 item==
Shopping Cart 1 item(s) - $100
```

**But what I'm hoping to get is**

```
==For O item==
Shopping Cart 0

==For 1 item==
Shopping Cart 1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: And where is the problem? This is as simple as editing the language file and removing the unwanted part from the translation...

Comment: Ohh, Great. it is simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up the language file for header (e.g. `catalog/language/<YOUR_LANG>/common/header.php`), search for this translation:

```
"Shopping Cart %s item(s) - %s"
```

and simply change it to

```
"Shopping Cart %s"
```

That's it.

Comment: Hi, I have try this in OpenCart 2.2. So, it is working fine. but, does show default style when add or remove item from mini-cart.